# How to read from Queue in READ ONLY MODE in Spring Integration

Tags: jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

When message Listener in Spring integration is started, it is pulling messages and removing from the source queue, How to stop the delete of messages from source queue?

Answer (score 0):

Make your listener `transactional` and rollback transaction, when the message from queue will be in your hands:

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter channel="input"
        connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager"
        destination-name="MY-QUEUE"/>

<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="input" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="input" order="1" ref="service" output-channel="output"/>

<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="input" order="1"   
        expression="T(org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport)
             .currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly()"/>
```

But here is need to understand what are you going to do with that remained message in the queue: it becomes available for Listener on the next poll...

Comment: thanks Artem ... is there any book or tutorial which clearly give examples ?

Comment: Not sure. That my thought is just expiriance. I haven't read books on the matter. Sorry.